# webcam not working

Tags: webcam, streaming, camera, uvc

I have a usb webcamera, which isnt working right.  when i run cheese, or streamer, the light comes on, but I never get video or photo output. here is what dmesg says:

```
[151626.040060] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[151626.234771] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5710
[151626.234784] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[151626.234790] usb 1-4: Product: USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam
[151626.234796] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Azurewave
[151626.234801] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 0x0001
[151626.237779] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam (13d3:5710)
[151626.244399] input: USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input31
```

I looked into UVC cameras a little, and tried installing guvcview, but I am never able to take a photo or make a video. is there something I should try for this UVC device?
Cheese doesnt say no device found, instead it says nothing, and shows a black screen.
I am looking for any ideas that can help me solve this,and get this camera working..

Comment: Its actually seems to be like driver issue check whether its updated with latest driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiho,

try it with fswebcam

```
sudo aptitude install fswebcam
```

then try this

```
DIR=/your/dir/goes/here
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H_%M.jpg")

#take the shot
fswebcam -d v4l2:/dev/YOUR/DEVICE -D 3 -S 20 -F 20 -r 1280x720 --jpeg 100 --set brightness=65% --set contrast=5% --set gamma=100 --set sharpness=0 --set saturation=45% ${DIR}/shot_${DATE}
```

Whats a bit strange is, that your device (input) seems to be located here

```
[151626.244399] input: USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input31
```

That's a bit odd, because I'd have expected something like `/dev/video0` 
Maybe doublecheck that, go to /dev first andd take a look if there is a device with video in it. And also make sure to terst if the device emntioned in the log really does exist.

[If it still won't work, please check with this site, if the camera is compatible with this driver.](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices)

Comment: it turns on the LED, but returns with: Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured. Ive also located some posts in Arch and Fedora Forums, where users had similar problems. No solutions though.

Comment: Looks like this might be a driver problem then. Could yo find a device in /dev, like I asked?

I've updated my answer

Comment: oh, sorry yeah, it shows up as /dev/video0 if its the only video device.